# Como compartilhar dados de uma aplicação web?

Tags: aplicação-web, cookies

Eu tenho o seguinte problema, tenho uma aplicação feita em (HTML, CSS JS, JQuey) outra aplicação está em ReactJS, nessa primeira aplicação ela está hospedada e em um dominio diferente por exemplo https://exemplo-a.com.br/ e a outra está em https://exemplo-b.amazonaws.com, localmente foi feito um teste passando os dados pelo cookies e funcionou, porém pesquisando vimos que não é possivel compartilhar dados entre dominios diferente em cookies, tem alguma outra maneira de resolver esse problema de compartilhamento ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o ideal seja utilizar/criar um banco de dados em um servidor, para manipular essas informações e com uma API você armazena as informações que você captar em um domínio e faz a request dessas informações no outro domínio. Acredito que essa seja a melhor alterantiva, ainda mais se os dados que precisarem ser manipulados forem sensíveis.